# How to select top records in multiple columns in Microsoft Access or SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

Each record in the database has multiple columns.

How to select those records that belong to the top 100 records in **both** column X **and** column Y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select *
from table_name
where column_x in (
    select top 100 column_x
    from table_name 
    order by column_x )
and column_y in (
    select top 100 column_y
    from table_name
    order by column_y );
```

Comment: Just as a note, Access returns matches so top 100 may include more that 100 records, which means that this query may return almost any number of records.